# Get Street Address From Contact Swift

Tags: swift, cncontact

I create an app, user can select contact an then get name, birthday, and street address.
I can get & display name and birthday. But I can't get street address

here's my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var names: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var birthday: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!

var storeNames = ""
var storeBirthday = ""
var storeAddress = CNLabeledValue()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    names.text = storeNames
    birthday.text = storeBirthday
    address.text = String(storeAddress)
}

func getDateStringFromComponents(dateComponents: NSDateComponents) -> String! {
    if let date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(dateComponents) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

        return dateString
    }
    return nil
}

@IBAction func showContacts(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "birthday != nil")
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
    storeNames = contact.givenName //Get Names
    if let bday = contact.birthday?.date as NSDate! {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        let stringDate = formatter.stringFromDate(contact.birthday!.date!)
        //Their birthday as a String:
        storeBirthday = stringDate //Get Birthday
    }

    storeAddress = contact.postalAddresses[0]
    print(storeAddress)
}
```

it print like this

`<CNLabeledValue: 0x7fca63c12780: identifier=150C06A9-8008-4496-B27A-     CE2648622793, label=_$!<Work>!$_, value=<CNPostalAddress: 0x7fca63c0dce0: street=165 Davis Street, city=Hillsborough, state=CA, postalCode=94010, country=, countryCode=us, formattedAddress=(null)>>
2016-12-08 19:35:09.920 Birthdays[638:9739] plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService invalidated`

i'm sorry, but I don't know how to get street address

Comment: `storeAddress` is `CNPostalAddress` object. So `let streetAddress = storeAddress.street`?

Comment: `Value of type 'CNLabeledValue' has no member 'street'`

Comment: `let streetAddress = storeAddress.value.street`?

Comment: `value of type 'protocol<NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>' has no member 'street'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast the value of your `storeAddress` it is a `CNPostalAddress` object with the properties you need

```
if let address = storeAddress.value as? CNPostalAddress {

   let city = address.city
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way i found to get the address parsed into individual strings was like this:

```
let emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses.count > 0 ? contact.emailAddresses[0].value : ""
let address = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value.street)" : ""
let city = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value.city)" : ""
let state = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value.state)" : ""
let zipCode = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value.postalCode)" : ""
let country = contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 ? "\(contact.postalAddresses[0].value.country)" : ""
```

i am getting the values like this:

```
contact.postalAddresses[0].value.street
```